# Problems parsing a TCP-based TLV protocol in C++

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I am trying to implement a (T)LV protocol over TCP sending protocol buffers from a python client and receiving with a C++ server.

My code looks more or less like this:

```
char* buffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
int recvsize= 0;
// Filling my buffer with as much as possible.
while(true) {
  if(recvsize == RCVBUFSIZE) {
    break;
  } else if(recvsize+= recv(sock, buffer+recvsize, sizeof(buffer)-recvsize, 0) < 1) {
    break;
  }
}
//Parsing LV protocol
while(true) {
  unsigned short protosize= 0;
  //Copy first two bytes into protosize
  memcpy((char *) &protosize, buffer, sizeof(unsigned short));
  if(protosize == 0) { break; } // Protocol indicates EOM be setting length to "0"
  void* protomsg[protosize];
  memcpy(protomsg, buffer+sizeof(unsigned short), protosize);
  int msglength= sizeof(unsigned short)+protosize;
  //Now I'll move the whole buffer to the left so that I don't have to keep track of where I'm at.
  memmove(buffer, buffer+msglength, RCVBUFSIZE-msglength);
  protoMsg pm;
  if(!pm.ParseFromArray(protomsg, protosize)) { break; } // Parsing failed.
  // Do stuff with parsed message.
}
```

Now I have several problems:

- The while loop receiving the message never terminates. I suspect that the recv call blocks when there isn't any data left anymore while I expected it to return with an error. I have found the select function to check whether there's something to read. I will give that a try.
  But when I call receive only once to skip this problem (The message received comes in at ~10 bytes, so I expect all to be collected in one call.) I get another problem:
- memcpy and memmove don't seem to be working as expected. On the first loop the short is processed as expected (I receive the same value I send on the other side), but then everything from parsing of the protocol buffer fails. Have I misunderstood something?

**Edit:** Regarding the comment about ntohs -- I'm transmitting the short as little-endian currently, forgot to mention that. (I will change this still, btw.)

**Third edit:** The code now works, but I had to change the following:

```
char* buffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
int recvsize= 0;
// Filling my buffer with as much as possible.
while(true) {
  if(recvsize == RCVBUFSIZE) {
    break;
  } else if((recvsize+= recv(sock, buffer+recvsize, sizeof(buffer)-recvsize, 0)) < 1) {
    break;
  } else if(recvsize > 1) {
    unsigned short msglength= 0;
    memcpy((char *) &msglength, buffer+recvsize-sizeof(unsigned short), sizeof(unsigned short));
    if(msglength == 0) { break; } // Received a full transmission.
  }
}
```

So first I needed to add brackets around the `recvsize+= recv()` statement and second as the non-blocking method didn't work for some reason I am now checking whether the last two bytes that were transmitted translate to a 0 when read a unsigned short. This probably leads to a problem if I read a 0 by chance that is not the length field. I'll start another question about this probably.

I also changed `protomsg` to `char[]`, but I don't think this really changed anything. (I had parsing working with a void array already.. )

Comment: You should be calling `ntohs` on the received `short` (and call `htons` when sending it - "Network TO Host, Short"/"Host TO Network, Short")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message you receive is always around 10 bytes, and `RCVBUFSIZE` is more than that, you will never terminate until there is a error reading data. Also, the `buffer` variable in your code is an array of `RCVBUFSIZE` pointers, probably not what you want.

Modify your code as follows:

```
#define MINIMALMESSAGESIZE 10  // Or what the size may be
char buffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
int totalrecvsize= 0;
int recvsize= 0;
while(true) {
  if(totalrecvsize >= MINIMALMESSAGESIZE) {
    break;
  } else if(recvsize= recv(sock, buffer+totalrecvsize, sizeof(buffer)-totalrecvsize, 0) < 1) {
    break;
  } else {
    totalrecvsize += recvsize;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah right, I had forgotten the "+=" when transcribing from my source, it is there now in my original question.

I'm not sure how to the the minimal message size, as I can only figure that out by parsing the length field. Doing that would mean an extra call to recv which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Ah ok, just read your edit. The thing is I am currently only transmitting one protocol buffer which comes in at around 10 bytes. When deployed everything from one to 1000s of those should be transmitted and I'd like to get as many of these as fast as possible from the wire.

Comment: @dinyar: Don't forget to add the total received size to the buffer in the call to `recv`, or you will overwrite what you already received. Also, if you do not know the message size, then you can wait for ever in the call to `recv`, unless the socket it non-blocking of course, in which case an error will be returned.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that with `recvsize+= recv` I think. I'll look into making the socket non-blocking, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @dinyar: Saw your second comment now. In this case you only have to take care of not overwriting your buffer in the receiving loop. :)